# "proxy_set_header Upgrade" causes "real_ip_header" not working

Tags: nginx, x-forwarded-for

nginx config:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default keep-alive;
  'websocket' upgrade;
}
set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
set_real_ip_from 192.168.203.1;
real_ip_recursive on;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
....
location /
{
      gzip  off;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;#this line
      #proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
}
```

the "proxy_set_header Upgrade"  will causes forward request lost "X-Real-IP" header,if comment this line it will be working.
nginx version:1.20.0
thanks!

Comment: Any "proxy_set_header *"  will causes forward request lost "X-Real-IP" header